# how to show div on event.clientX mouse position 50vw

Tags: javascript, position, mouse

Hi all i am wondering if it is possible to find the mouse value of 50vw

i have figured out how to show and hide a div depending wether or not the mouse is so far on the X axis, what i want to achieve is only show or hide once past 50vw

any help would be appreciated, ive searched but cant find an answer

here is my code

```
document.body.addEventListener('mousemove', function (event) {

    if (event.clientX >= 500) {
        console.log("show div or addclass");
        
    } else {
        console.log("hide div or remove class");
    }
}, false);
```

update: i figured it out i added window.innerWidth/2  so used to css this never occurred to me

Comment: woop i figured it out i added window.innerWidth/2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you need?

```
const half_of_width = window.innerWidth / 2
document.addEventListener("mousemove", (event) => {console.log(event.clientX > half_of_width)})
```

Answer (score 0):

thanks for the reply i did a similar thing

```
if (event.clientX >= window.innerWidth/2) {
    console.log("show div or addclass");
    $("#choice2").fadeIn(500);
     $("#choice1").fadeOut(500);
   
 
    
    
} else {
    console.log("hide div or remove class");
    $("#choice1").fadeIn(500);
     $("#choice2").fadeOut(500);
   
}
```

}, false);